# how to get a list of all Oracle E-Business Suite 11i reports

Tags: oracle

I would love to have a list of all reports that can be generated in oracle E-business Suite 11i, i hope there is a concurrent programme that can do that, but so far, i have not been able to get any useful information.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reports in Oracle E-Business Suite, are easily obtained by retrieving the list of Concurrent Programs, and these will have all the reports.
And this can be obtained by running

```
Concurrent Programs Report
```

Concurrent  program, this will give you all concurrent program, per specified application.

But if you want to obtain a list of specific reports, per a given responsibility, it will be not sufficient just to run the above concurrent program, but you can get the list by running the following query which receives the responsibility name as a parameter

```
SELECT distinct fcpt.user_concurrent_program_name,
 fcpt.description,
 fa_vl.APPLICATION_NAME,
 fa_vl.application_short_name
FROM fnd_concurrent_programs_tl fcpt
    INNER JOIN fnd_request_group_units frgu
        ON fcpt.concurrent_program_id = frgu.request_unit_id 
        or
         fcpt.APPLICATION_ID = frgu.APPLICATION_ID
    INNER JOIN fnd_responsibility fr
        ON fr.request_group_id = frgu.request_group_id
    INNER JOIN fnd_responsibility_tl rsp_tl 
        ON fr.responsibility_id = rsp_tl.responsibility_id
    INNER JOIN FND_APPLICATION_VL fa_vl
        ON fa_vl.APPLICATION_ID = fcpt.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE upper(responsibility_name) = upper('RESPONSIBILITY_NAME')
```

where **RESPONSIBILY_NAME** is the input parameter

Answer (score 1):

try this report from Sys admin responsibiility Concurrent Programs Report

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mouly that was so helpful, but found a way to do this with a query.